# How use QTableView customized complicated table?

Tags: qt, pyqt

I want use `QTableView` to draw a complex table, the table style like bellow.

**Table style**
<sub>The header contain "C" char and row contain "Data" char</sub>
[image]

The problem is I don't know how to use pyqt to draw table like this, can someone have any ideas ?

Comment: You might take a look on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741610/setting-row-span-in-qtableview-using-python

Comment: @vahancho That is not a good method, but  in current is a best method.